# Creation of object with key/value pairs in a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, object

I have the following string:

```
person:juan&age:24&knowledge:html
```

The problem is that sometimes the string is:

```
knowledge:html&person:juan&age:24
```

And it can change the position of the keys and the values.

In this case I would write something like this:

```
const keys = ["person", "age", "knowledge"];
const keyAndValues = "person:juan&age:24&knowledge:html";

const result = [];

keys.forEach(key => {
  const indexKeyValues = keyAndValues.indexOf(key);
  if (indexKeyValues !== -1) {
    const lastCharIndex = keyAndValues.substring(indexKeyValues).indexOf("&");
    return keyAndValues.substring(indexKeyValues + key.length, lastCharIndex === -1 ? keyAndValues.substring(indexKeyValues).length - 1 || lastCharIndex);
  }
});
```

But I don't like it and it would be great if I could do something like:

```
const resultsExpected = /regexGroupedRegardlessOfPosition/g.match("person:juan&age:24&knowledge:html");

console.log(resultsExpected); // { person: "juan", age: 24, knowledge: "html" }
```

Comment: I don't think regex would be the best solution in this case. To be honest I don't even think it applies any solution for this problem.

Comment: Why may be there is a way to grab things in between : and the begining of the chain to see if it belongs to a key and then grab the value

Comment: I think you should go with what you have if it works. It's simple and readable, which in honesty, regex seldom is.

Comment: It looks like you'd be better off splitting the string on `&` and then splitting each result on `:`

Comment: Sounds reasonable @MattBurland that would make it more readable too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a single expression to get the object:

```js
const keyAndValues = "person:juan&age:24&knowledge:html";

const obj = Object.assign(...keyAndValues.split('&').map(s => s.split(':'))
                                         .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))
);

console.log(obj);
```

This uses ES6 [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

Comment: If we define only one "map" instead of 2 would it make it with less iterations?

Comment: Wonderfully terse, but @juangarcia: Just beware that using `split` for the `:` part assumes the value will never contain a `:`, of course. (This also creates a throwaway object per entry, but JavaScript engines are fast at creating and throwing away objects.)

Comment: @juangarcia, you could do it with one `map`, but then you would need to store the result of `split` in variables, and then return the synthesised object from those: that is not so elegant as two `map` calls, each with their own expression. True, you have an extra iteration, but it also serves the purpose of the destructuring assignment, and does not influence the overall time complexity.

Answer (score 3):

You could split the string and then the parts and take the key/values for an object.

```js
function getValues(string) {
    var object = {};
    
    string && string.split('&').forEach(p => {
        var [key, ...value] = p.split(':');
        object[key] = value.join(':');
    });
    return object;
}

console.log(getValues("knowledge:html&person:juan&age:24"));
console.log(getValues("foo:bar:baz&cool:space:aliens:survive"));
console.log(getValues(""));
```

Comment: This is ES6 syntax, right? The part where you create `var [key, value]`?

Comment: @Phiter, right, it's an [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Comment: Using `split` for the `:` part assumes the value will never contain a `:`, of course.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, in this case some escaping is required.

Comment: @NinaScholz: No, no escaping required. The delimiter between entries is `&`. See my answer.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Heh, cute solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
(knowledge|person|age):([^&]+)
```

You probably don't want to, but to accept any key:

```
(\w+):([^&]+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/HwW5I1/1/

Answer (score 1):

As [Phiter said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994206/creation-of-a-regex-with-string-of-key-and-values-varies-on-the-position-of-the/48994342#comment84993720_48994206), I don't think regex really helps you here. You probably know the old joke: "I have a problem. I know! I'll use regex! Oh, now I have two problems."

I'd split the string on `&`, and then for each substring, on `:`, and fill in the values from that:

```
function strToObject(str) {
  var rv = {};
  str.split("&").forEach(function(substr) {
    var index = substr.indexOf(":");
    if (index === -1) {
      rv[substr] = undefined;
    } else {
      rv[substr.substring(0, index)] = substr.substring(index+1);
    }
  });
  return rv;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function strToObject(str) {
  var rv = {};
  str.split("&").forEach(function(substr) {
    var index = substr.indexOf(":");
    if (index === -1) {
      rv[substr] = undefined;
    } else {
      rv[substr.substring(0, index)] = substr.substring(index+1);
    }
  });
  return rv;
}

console.log(strToObject("person:juan&age:24&knowledge:html"));
console.log(strToObject("knowledge:html&person:juan&age:24"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

This could be made terser, by:

- Using ES2015+ syntax.
- By creating unnecessary temporary objects *(JavaScript engines are quick at creating and destroying objects, though, so the brevity can be worth the cost)*.
- Assuming values never contain `:` characters. I've used `indexOf` rather than the simpler `split` to separate name and value to allow for the possibility that the value will contain a `:` (e.g., `foo:blah:blah&bar:blah` where `foo` is `"blah:blah"`) — many if not most other solutions here throw away part of the value in that case

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple function that would convert this type of string to an object can be a better solution. Look at this:

```js
var keyAndValues = "person:juan&age:24&knowledge:html";

function weirdStringToObject(str){
    var obj = {};
    str.split('&').forEach(function(substr){
        var kv = substr.split(':');
        var key = kv[0];
        var value = kv[1] || null;
        obj[key] = value;
    });
    return obj;
}

console.log(weirdStringToObject(keyAndValues));
```

It requires a little bit of extra validation, but it's easy to follow from here.

Comment: I used `map` in my first implementation but that was dumb. I noticed after I started writing that It's impossible to return `key:value` pairs with `.map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of:

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)
- [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

**Working Example:**

```js
const str = "person:juan&age:24&knowledge:html";

let result = str.split("&").reduce((r, s) => {
  let i = s.indexOf(':');
  r[s.slice(0, i)] = s.slice(i + 1);
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```